# Single-page application - Allow a user to upload a photo/video and fill out fields in one form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, video

New to the community so please don't be hard on me!

I have the following two questions:

Question 1:
I am trying to create a single page application that allows users to upload a photo (in any format) or video (also in any format). The issue(?) I'm facing is that we must use two different hosting services -- Google WS for photos and Vzaar for video.

Is it possible to create ONE form that allows the user to upload a file of their choice (video/photo) while they fill out fields that belong to that video?

Question 2:
We are using the MEAN stack for this application. Do we need to use iframes in order to get this to work properly across all platforms?

Thanks.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per question.

Comment: 1. It depends on how much you want to involve your server, but probably.

Comment: 2. Are you making a single page application or not? SPAs don't use iframes. What platforms do you include in "all"? Do you want full functionality in Lynx?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, Quentin..and I'm sorry about asking two questions. I am making an SPA but I heard other companies like YouTube and Facebook still use iframes. I'm not sure what lynx is but I will look that up.

Answer (score 0):

I will only refer to the first question here:
Since have tagged the post with "angular", I guess you use angular as the SPA-Framework. In angular you can easily create something like you asked for. You would create a controller that shows/hides fields that are needed for the current mask (video/photo) and for example dropzone.js could handle the upload of the object (video/photo) to the specified location with the given URL and accountdata. The main problem is the handling of the different locations where you store your data but this could easily handled by the angular controller.

Comment: Hi plasmalampe, thanks a lot for answering the question!